# Prevent Google from rewriting search results link

Tags: google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google search results - getting actual links](https://superuser.com/questions/445222/google-search-results-getting-actual-links)

I'm using Firefox.

When I hover over a link in Google search results, it shows the correct link target (e.g. `www.example.com`). As soon as I click (or right-click) on it, it turns into a http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web... link with the real link buried deep inside, making it irritatingly difficult to copy-and-paste the right link.

Any way to prevent Google from doing this (e.g. a preference?), or is there a Greasemonkey script which can suppress this behaviour?

Comment: Chrome Browser doesnt do this with their own links for search results. Havent found a solution that works for Firefox in 2022: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/84141/30586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got Now.. You can have [Scrub Google Redirect Links](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/24102) which removes the Google redirect in search result links.

Comment: No, Google could use *the original link*. I want to be able to right-click and use "Copy link address". And, copying that green URL doesn't work if the URL gets clipped (`...`).

Comment: check above link

Comment: Link fails with ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.